# Angular 4.0+ calendar http get to Asp.net core 1.1

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, calendar

I am working with this Angular 4 calendar:

> https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar

I am trying to make a request to the api following the async method recommended in the github page, but it does not make the request unless if I use .toPromise(), but with that I do not know how to map

Here is my get of my calendar-component.ts:

```
params = new URLSearchParams();
options = new RequestOptions();
events: any[];
events$: Observable<Array<CalendarEvent<{ event: EventCalendar }>>>;
/***/
getEvents()
{
    const getStart: any = {
        month: startOfMonth,
        week: startOfWeek,
        day: startOfDay
    }[this.view];
    const getEnd: any = {
        month: endOfMonth,
        week: endOfWeek,
        day: endOfDay
    }[this.view];

    this.params.set('beginning', format(getStart(this.viewDate), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    this.params.set('end', format(getEnd(this.viewDate), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    this.options.search = this.params

    this.http
        .request(ApiConfig.API_URL + 'calendar/RangeEvents', this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(() =>
        {
            res => res.json()
            .map(({ results }: { results: EventCalendar[] }) =>
            {
                results.map((event: EventCalendar) =>
                {
                    return {
                        title: event.title,
                        start: event.date,
                        color: colors.yellow,
                        allDay: true,
                        meta: {
                            event
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        })
}
```

I get the the request if I use this, but the html calendar does not get the events:

```
this.http
    .get(ApiConfig.API_URL + 'calendar/RangeEvents', this.options)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response =>
    {
        this.events$ = response.json()
    })
```

And I got this from Api:

> {title: "Event 1", date: "2017-10-10T10:34:09"}

Html:

```
<mwl-demo-utils-calendar-header [(view)]="view"
                                  [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
                                  (viewDateChange)="fetchEvents()"
                                  (viewChange)="fetchEvents()">
  </mwl-demo-utils-calendar-header>

  <ng-template #loading>
    <div class="text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" style="font-size:40px"></i>
      <br>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

  <div *ngIf="events$ | async; else loading; let events">
    <div [ngSwitch]="view">
      <mwl-calendar-month-view *ngSwitchCase="'month'"
                               [viewDate]="viewDate"
                               [events]="events"
                               [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen"
                               (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)"
                               (eventClicked)="eventClicked($event.event)">
      </mwl-calendar-month-view>
      <mwl-calendar-week-view *ngSwitchCase="'week'"
                              [viewDate]="viewDate"
                              [events]="events"
                              (eventClicked)="eventClicked($event.event)">
      </mwl-calendar-week-view>
      <mwl-calendar-day-view *ngSwitchCase="'day'"
                             [viewDate]="viewDate"
                             [events]="events"
                             (eventClicked)="eventClicked($event.event)">
      </mwl-calendar-day-view>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is your third map method called ?

Comment: I am getting now the request but I do not know how to map to this.events$, I am following the async request of the github

Comment: Can you add the html template of your component ?

Comment: added the html code